# Find text by regex and add new text after it

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, regex-group

I have a JSON file with the following structure.

```
{"json":[
  { "text":"Changed by 5" },
  { "text":"Changed by 345" },
  { "text":"Changed by 32" }
]}
```

In Intellij Idea if I want to find all texts by regex I use `\bby [0-9]+`. Then I want to add new text after what I found like that:

```
{"json":[
  { "text":"Changed by 5, done" },
  { "text":"Changed by 345, done" },
  { "text":"Changed by 32, done" }
]}
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: [Find and **replace** in path](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/replace-the-found-target.html)? Check the https://superuser.com/questions/1200488/add-text-at-the-end-of-the-specific-lines-notepad-regex for regex example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that some expressions similar to:

```
(\sby [0-9]+)
```

or:

```
("text":".*by [0-9]+)
```

or:

```
("text":".*\s+by [0-9]+)
```

being replaced with the capturing group, `$1` and `, done`:

```
$1, done
```

might actually work here.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ha0yb2/1/)